# Can I change from shapes to graphics in Corona SDK? (app reskinning)

Tags: android, sdk, coronasdk

I am brand new to app reskinning (and coding in general), but I have run into the same problem with a couple of the source codes I purchased. the apps use shapes as the "characters", but I would like to replace them with graphics. In other words, instead of simply choosing a Fill Color, I want to use my own images.

I contacted one of the developers for one of the apps, who told me that to do this would require rewriting a large part of the code. I've been trying to figure it out myself with Google, but I'm stuck. I'm willing to put in the work of rewriting it if someone could point me in the right direction, or even suggest a tutorial showing the process.

```
local Settings = display.newImage("images/Settings.png");
Settings.x = FrameXPos2;
Settings.y = _H / 2;
Settings:scale(_H / 1300, _H / 1280);

Ball_Player = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (25 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ))
Ball_Player:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Ball_Player.alpha = 0;

Ball_Player1 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (25 * ((GameScreen.width    * (_H / 1300))) / 700)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ))
Ball_Player1:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Ball_Player1.alpha = 0;

Ball_Player2 = display.newCircle( Player2X, Player2Y, (25 *     ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 700)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ))
Ball_Player2:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Ball_Player2.alpha = 0;

Ball_Enemy1 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (35 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600));
Ball_Enemy1:setFillColor(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
Ball_Enemy1.alpha = 0;
```

Comment: Your question is lacking some of the required information. Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an image to fill your shapes, something like:

```
local paint = {
type = "image",
filename = "texture1.png"
}

local rect = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (25 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ) )
rect.fill = paint
```

Probably that is the best to re-shape your game easy.

`display.newImage()` and `display.newCircle()` are both shapes, but you will need to check all changes you need to do. If you use physics the changes could be more difficult.